# Git под Windows

Tags: windows, git

Добрый день.

Нужно поставить git на Windows. Подскажите, что поставить? И если можно, графический интерфейс.

На  вики смотрел, но хотел бы узнать мнение от тех, кто с чем работал.

Comment: и не будет проблем с Linux-им git-ом? (по идеи не должен конечно)

Comment: http://windows.github.com/ или http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ + http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/

Comment: А вы сами использовали? Все нормально, проблем не было?

Comment: Ну, интеграция, например, в `Visual Studio` - это отдельный вопрос, но с `GitHub` клиентом особенных траблов не возникло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хех, только что статью на хабре читал про это ;)

[Разворачиваем локальный сервер на Windows](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150972/).